# Using short circuit to control program flow - anti pattern?

Tags: java, anti-patterns, short-circuiting

Suppose if I need to create a database connection for query. I'll make sure the jdbc driver is present and also the connection is created before I start sending queries.

Suppose if I have three methods that returns boolean:

```
public boolean verifyJDBCDriverExist()
public boolean createConnection()
public boolean sendQueries()
```

I can write something that looks like:

```
if(verifyJDBCDriverExist()&&createConnection()&&sendQueries());
```

the short-circuit behaviour will make sure the sendQueries is only executed when both verifyJDBCDriverExist and createConnection is sucessful. I think it's pretty easy to understand what it's trying to do.
Is this an anti-pattern? Why?

Comment: I think this is opinion based. I say "It's bad" because it is an "if", I'm expecting it to do something, so now I'm checking to see if you've added a semicolon after the expression without meaning to... Not sure if I'd go so far as calling it an anti pattern though.

Comment: I would expect each of those methods to throw an exception to you if it failed, rather than catch them internally. I would also expect that unless you only have one set of queries to execute, that your program would establish its DataSource or Driver first and not get anywhere near logic that executes queries if that fails.

Comment: @EJP it's just an example for to clarify one of the possible use-case.